# Jquery array send by ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I viewed so many post aboit this but still cant get my code to work.

I want to get a php array of my checked checkboxes values.

heres my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

 <?php


echo'<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox"  name="cim"  value="valami">';
echo'<input type="checkbox"  name="cim"  value="valami2">';
echo'<input type="checkbox"  name="cim"  value="valami3">';
echo'<input type="checkbox"  name="cim"  value="valami4">
<input type="submit" value="Felvisz" name="feladat"></form>';

if (isset($_POST['feladat'])) {

?>  
<script type="text/javascript">

var checkedValue = $('.messageCheckbox:checked').val();

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(checkedValue);

$.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "proba.php",
       data: { tomb : myJSON },
       success: function(){
alert("OK");
}
    }); 

</script>

<?php

var_dump($_POST);

$array = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['tomb']));
foreach($array as $arr){
    echo $arr;
}

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Massages i got:
Notice: Undefined index: tomb in D:\programok\xamp\htdocs\SZAKDOGA\Dropbox\proba.php on line 48

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\programok\xamp\htdocs\SZAKDOGA\Dropbox\proba.php on line 49

Please someone can help me to solve this?

Comment: `json_decode` is unnecessary here. ajax will send data as an array object. to get only the values of "checked" checkboxes you need to test them. you currently don't have the class you're testing the checkboxes with assigned to any of the boxes

Comment: better using this?

var values = $("input[name='cim']")
              .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

Answer (score 2):

To get an array , you must convert the name to accept multiple so  change the input's :

```
name="cim"
```

to

```
name="cim[]"
```

Also your jquery ajax function should be this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$("form").on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var checkedValue = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "proba.php",
       data: checkedValue,
       success: function(){
   alert("OK");
   }

});//end ajax 


});//end form submit
});
</script>
```

in php the cim will be the array example

```
var_dump($_POST["cim"]);
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

currently, you are testing for checked boxes with class `messageChecked`. assign your checkboxes that class, give your form an `id`, then test for checked condition on each checkbox,

```
 $('#yourForm').each(function() {
    if($('.messageChecked').is(':checked')) {
        checkedValue.push($('.messageChecked:checked').val());
    }
 }
```

now send it to your php script via ajax,

```
 $.ajax({        
   type: "POST",
   url: "proba.php",
   data: { tomb : (checkedValue) },
   success: function(){
      alert("OK");
   }
 });
```

if done like this you can remove `json_decode` and `stripslashes` from your `$_POST` statement